# Variable generic type count runtime reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, switch-statement, refactoring, variable-assignment

Right now I have this code:

```
//some Method detection here..

var methodParams = method.GetParameters();
Type actionType = null;

switch(methodParams.Length)
{
    case 1:
        actionType = typeof(Action<>);
        break;

    case 2:
        actionType = typeof(Action<,>);
        break;

    case 3:
        actionType = typeof(Action<,,>);
        break;

    case 4:
        actionType = typeof(Action<,,,>);
        break;

    case 5:
        actionType = typeof(Action<,,,,>);
        break;
}

var actionGenericType = actionType.MakeGenericType(methodParams.Select(x => x.ParameterType).ToArray());
```

I don't like this switch statement but I haven't yet found a way to select the Action generic overload based on the number of parameters (or based on any runtime `int`).

Is there a more elegant way / oneliner to do something like this?

I don't want to use a dispatch table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I can see in the debugger, `actionType` can be obtained as:

```
var actionType = Type.GetType("System.Action`" + methodParams.Length);
```

Comment: That's a back-tick, by the way (up over by the `1` on a QWERTY keyboard)

Comment: Exactly, and the same symbol is used in SO markup :-)